# How to create an Edit-with-Vim context menu entry for Vim 8.1 on Windows 10

Tags: microsoft-windows, installing

The Explorer context menu entry does not get created by the installer. Windows 10 Pro v1803 (64-bit).

What I have already tried:

1. Installed Vim 8.1 using the stock Windows installer https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim81.exe.

   Took the installer option "Add an Edit-with-Vim context menu entry".

   Used a Windows user profile with administrator rights. Also tried starting the installer "Run as administrator".
2. Verified the registry entries, including correct path names, going by the articles:

   - “[Adding Vim to MS-Windows File Explorer Menu](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Adding_Vim_to_MS-Windows_File_Explorer_Menu)” at *Vim Tips Wiki*
   - “[Vim documentation: gui_w32](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_w32.html)” at *SourceForge*

   These articles covered versions prior to 8.1 but still seemed relevant.

Here are the registry entries called out by the articles above. These are the entries that I actually have on the problem PC.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vim\Gvim]
"path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}]
@="Vim Shell Extension"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\GvimExt64\\gvimext.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\gvim]
@="{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Approved]
"{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}"="Vim Shell Extension"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Vim 8.1]
"DisplayName"="Vim 8.1 (self-installing)"
"UninstallString"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\uninstall-gui.exe"
```

There are of course many other Vim related registry entries. Most are plainly nothing to do with the Edit-with-Vim context menu entry for the 64-bit OS. The ones I reproduce below are the ones I could not personally rule out as unrelated to the problem.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\OpenWithList\gvim.exe]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\gvim.exe\shell\edit\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1]
@="Vim OLE Interface 1.1 Type Library"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1\0\win32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1\FLAGS]
@="0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1\HELPDIR]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Vim.Application]
@="Vim"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Vim.Application\CLSID]
@="{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Vim.Application\CurVer]
@="Vim.Application.1"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Vim.Application.1]
@="Vim"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Vim.Application.1\CLSID]
@="{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}]
@="Vim"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\LocalServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\ProgID]
@="Vim.Application.1"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\TypeLib]
@="{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{0F0BFAE1-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\VersionIndependentProgID]
@="Vim.Application"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}]
@="Vim Shell Extension"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{51EEE242-AD87-11d3-9C1E-0090278BBD99}\InProcServer32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\GvimExt32\\gvimext.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1]
@="Vim OLE Interface 1.1 Type Library"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1\0\win32]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Vim\\vim81\\gvim.exe"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\TypeLib\{0F0BFAE0-4C90-11D1-82D7-0004AC368519}\1.1\FLAGS]
@="0"
```

Comment: For me.. the entry did get added to the menu option..

Comment: Do you have vim associated with the '*' filetype?

Comment: @HerbWolfe I remember an association with the '*' filetype. From where I am, I can't access it to export and post the actual registry entry. When I look at that association what should I be looking for?

Comment: @HerbWolfe I didn't find any Vim keys under the `*` filetype (other than the ones listed above, `HKCR\*\OpenWithList\gvim.exe` and `HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\gvim`).

Comment: I'm not sure, I just remember that I had issues with the context menu when installing Vim on Windows 8.1, due to changes in the registry. The settings in Windows 7 did not work. Additionally, I use the Windows vim installer without cream at http://cream.sourceforge.net/download.html